# Register return values from tasks_from when looping over include_role

Tags: ansible

I'd like to build an array of ticket numbers that are created by the `create_srq.yaml` task in role `servicenow`.  Is it possible to do this when looping over an `include_role`?

`roles/request_signed_certificate/tasks/main.yaml`

```
- name: Create SNOW Records for Certificate Request
  include_role:
    name: servicenow
    tasks_from: create_srq.yaml
  register: result
  loop: "{{ spreadsheet }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: csr
  vars:
    short_description: CSR for {{ csr.certname }}-{{ csr.env }}
    attachment: "{{ cert_path }}/{{ csr.certname }}-{{ csr.env }}.csr"

- name: debug
  debug:
    var: result
```

`roles/servicenow/tasks/create_srq.yaml`

```
- name: Create a SRQ
  snow_record:
    state: present
    table: u_request
    username: "{{ snow_username }}"
    password: "{{ snow_password }}"
    instance: "{{ servicenow_instance }}"
    data:
      short_description: "{{ short_description }}"
      attachment: "{{ attachment }}"
  register: srq

- name: Attach file to {{ srq.record.number }}
  snow_record:
    state: present
    table: u_request
    username: "{{ snow_username }}"
    password: "{{ snow_password }}"
    instance: "{{ servicenow_instance }}"
    number: "{{ srq.record.number }}"
    attachment: "{{ attachment }}"
```

When running the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ hosts_list }}"
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cert_path: "/tmp/certs"
    cert_version: "2023"
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Create facts from csv
      csv_to_facts:
        src: "file.csv"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
  roles:
    - role: request_signed_certificate
```

The result does not include the registered `srq` variable from `create_srq.yaml`:

```
TASK [request_signed_certificate : debug] **************************************************************
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "csr",
                "csr": {
                    "certname": "example_one",
                    "common_name": "domain_one.example.com",
                    "dns1": "domain_two.example.com",
                    "env": "development",
                },
                "include_args": {
                    "name": "servicenow",
                    "tasks_from": "create_srq.yaml"
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "csr",
                "csr": {
                    "certname": "example_two",
                    "common_name": "domain_123.example.com",
                    "dns1": "domain_456.example.com",
                    "env": "test",
                },
                "include_args": {
                    "name": "servicenow",
                    "tasks_from": "create_srq.yaml"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You are registering the variable `srq` in the role, and it can be directly accessed later. Have you tried debugging `var: srq`?

Comment: yes - I only get the value from the last iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by appending results to a list.  While this works, it wasn't exactly what I was after as I would have preferred to install a reusable role to create the srqs.

Adding this bit to the bottom of `create_srq.yaml` gave me what I was looking for:

```
- name: output csv entry + ticket number
  set_fact:
    csv: "{{ csv | default({}) | combine ( { item.key : item.value } ) | combine( { 'ticket': srq.record.number } ) }}"
  loop: "{{ csr | dict2items }}"

# Create list of dictionaries to track
# also, a list is required for the to_csv plugin
- name: create list of dicts
  set_fact:
    contents: "{{ contents | default([]) + [ csv ] }}"
```